# Cast Any to Bool or Int with possible values of 1 or 0 in UserDefaults Swift

Tags: swift

I have enum that goes through possible values of Any (it's actually possible value stored in UserDefaults)

```
let rawValue = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: key)

        switch rawValue {
        case let value as Int:
            return int(value)
        case let value as Bool:
            return bool(value)
```

The problem is, it never returns `bool`, it rather returns `Int(1)` or `Int(0)`
Well, i could cast `Int(1)` or `Int(0)` to true or false respectively, but what if i actually store 1 or 0?

Comment: Consider a solution where you can use bool(forKey:) etc instead of using Any

Comment: `value(forKey:)` is the worst choice, you don't need KVC at all. There is `bool(forKey:)` and `integer(forKey:)`. If the value in `UserDefaults` is an instance of `NSNumber` both APIs are possible.

Comment: @vadian Perhaps rewrite that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use Key-Value Coding `value(forKey:)` of `UserDefaults` to just read a value. There is `object(forKey:)` for reference type objects and some APIs like `integer(forKey:)` and `double(forKey:)` for value type scalar values.

Due to its Objective-C inheritance a `Bool` is stored as `NSNumber` object and can be read with dedicated API `bool(forKey:)` Unlike the reference types which can return `nil` it returns a non-optional `Bool` and `false` if the key doesn't exist.

Side note:

Your `switch` returns an `Int` because the `NSNumber` instance can also be cast to `Int`. If you change the order of the switch

```
switch rawValue {
   case let value as Bool:
      return bool(value)
    case let value as Int:
      return int(value)
```

it will return a `Bool`, because the first pattern match leaves the switch.

Comment: The re-ordering introduces the opposite problem: `0` would be interpreted as `false`, and `1` as `true`. I think the only way to tell them apart is by checking their `objCType`

Comment: @Alexander Actually a type check of an UserDefaults value at runtime is pretty poor practice. The developer is supposed to know what type has been saved.